# python filters not founding results

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, filter, jinja2, webapp2

I'm filtering data from database for side bar search .

I creating filter for search but "owner" filter is working the other two filters "Nice  Classification" and "Application no." are not working and showing  No results Found . just check image for clear idea

The code is below python 2.7 and webapp2 frame work has been used in here.

> Owner filter result

[image: ![enter image description here]

> "Nice  Classification" and "Application no."

[image] [image]

**sidebar.html**

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
<section class="sidebar">
  <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
    <h3 style="color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px;">Filters</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Markname</label>
            <input id="s_query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Owners</label>
        <select id="s_assignees" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
        {% for assignee in project.assignees%}
          <option value="{{assignee}}">{{assignee}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </div>    


     <div class="form-group">
            <label> Nice classification </label>
            <select id="s_classes" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
            {% for cl in project.classes %}
              <option value="{{cl}}">{{cl}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
            <label> Application Number </label>
            <select id="s_applicationNo" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
            {% for ap in project.applicationNo   %}
              <option value="{{ap}}">{{ap}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
            </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Legal Status</label>
        <select id="s_legalStatus" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
        {% for ls in project.legalStatus%}
          <option value="{{ls}}">{{ls}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </div>  

    <button type="button" id="s_filter-btn" data-tid="" onclick="filtering_sidebar();" class="btn btn-sm bg-blue">Filter</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

> this is the filtering_sidebar(); function on view report page

viewreport.html

```
function filtering_sidebar(){
    var taxonomy_id = '';
    var items = [];
    $('#s_assignees option:selected').each(function(){ items.push($(this).val()); });
    var assignees = items.join(',');


    var items1 = [];
    $('#s_classes option:selected').each(function(){ items1.push($(this).val()); });
    var classes = items1.join(',');

    var items2 = [];
    $('#s_applicationNo option:selected').each(function(){ items2.push($(this).val()); });
    var applicationNo = items2.join(',');


    var items3 = [];
    $('#s_legalStatus option:selected').each(function(){ items3.push($(this).val()); });
    var legalStatus = items3.join(',');
    console.log(legalStatus);

    var ado = $('#s_a_date').val();
    var ad1 = $('#s_a_date_start').val();
    var ad2 = $('#s_a_date_end').val();

    var tiabTxt = $('#s_query').val();
    var flag = $('#s_flag').val();

    var win = window.open('/t/filter-report/{{project.pid}}?tid=' + taxonomy_id + '&owners=' + encodeURIComponent(assignees) +
                            '&classes=' + encodeURIComponent(classes) + '&applicationNo=' + encodeURIComponent(applicationNo)  +
                            '&legalStatus=' + encodeURIComponent(legalStatus) +
                            '&ado=' + ado + '&ad1=' + ad1 + '&ad2=' + ad2 +
                            '&query=' + tiabTxt + '&flag=' + flag, '_blank');
    if (win) {
        win.focus();
    } else {
        alert('Please allow popups for this website');
    }

}
```

> here is our handler for this

```
class FilterTMReportHandler(UserSessionHandler):
@login_required
def get(self, pid):
    user = self.user_session_info
    pid = str(urllib2.unquote(pid))
    tid = self.request.get('tid')

    owners = self.request.get('owners')
    classes = self.request.get('classes')
    applicationNo = self.request.get('applicationNo')
    legalStatus = self.request.get('legalStatus')
    ado = self.request.get('ado')
    ad1 = self.request.get('ad1')
    ad2 = self.request.get('ad2')
    pdo = self.request.get('pdo')
    pd1 = self.request.get('pd1')
    pd2 = self.request.get('pd2')
    rdo = self.request.get('rdo')
    rd1 = self.request.get('rd1')
    rd2 = self.request.get('rd2')
    query = self.request.get('query')
    flag = self.request.get('flag')




    filters_dict = dict(owners=owners,
                        classes=classes,
                        applicationNo=applicationNo,
                        legalStatus=legalStatus,
                        ado=ado, ad1=ad1, ad2=ad2,
                        pdo=pdo,pd1=pd1,pd2=pd2,
                        rdo=rdo, rd1=rd1, rd2=rd2,
                        query=query, flag=flag)


    taxonomy_items = []

    prj_key = ndb.Key('YoProject', long(pid))

    project = YoProject.get_by_key_query(prj_key).get()

    file_blob_key = 'NA'
    if project.file_blob_key is not None:
        file_blob_key = project.file_blob_key

    project_dict = dict(name=project.project_name,
                        pid=pid,
                        client=project.client_name,
                        client_spoc_name=project.client_spoc_name,
                        assignees=project.assignees,
                        file_blob_key=file_blob_key,
                        type_=project.type_,
                        applicationNo=project.applicationNo,
                        description=project.description,
                        taxonomy_id=project.taxonomy_id)

    taxonomy_key = ndb.Key('Taxonomy', long(project.taxonomy_id))
    taxonomy = Taxonomy.get_by_key_query(taxonomy_key).get()

    taxonomy_l1s = TaxonomyItem.query(ndb.AND(TaxonomyItem.taxonomy_id == str(project.taxonomy_id), TaxonomyItem.level == 1)).fetch()

    for taxonomy_l1 in taxonomy_l1s:
        results = []

        tm_result_query = TrademarkResult.query(ndb.AND(TrademarkResult.project_id ==str(pid), 
                                                    TrademarkResult.taxonomy_id == str(project.taxonomy_id),
                                                    TrademarkResult.taxonomyItem == taxonomy_l1.name))


        if len(owners) != 0:
            a_list = owners.split(",")
            tm_query_updated = tm_result_query.filter(TrademarkResult.ownerNames.IN(a_list))
        else:
            tm_query_updated = tm_result_query

        if len(classes) != 0:
            c_list = classes.split(",")
            tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.classes.IN(c_list))  

        if len(applicationNo) != 0:
            ap_list = applicationNo.split(",")
            tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationNo.IN(ap_list))


        if len(legalStatus) != 0:
            ls_list = legalStatus.split(",")
            tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.legalStatus.IN(ls_list))

        if len(ad1) != 0:
            if ado == 'after':
                tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationDate >= datetime.datetime.strptime(str(ad1), '%m/%d/%Y'))

            if ado == 'before':
                tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationDate <= datetime.datetime.strptime(str(ad1), '%m/%d/%Y'))

            if ado == 'between' and len(ad2) != 0:
                tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationDate >= datetime.datetime.strptime(str(ad1), '%m/%d/%Y'))
                tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationDate <= datetime.datetime.strptime(str(ad2), '%m/%d/%Y'))

        if len(flag) != 0:
            tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.flag == int(flag))


        tm_result_keys = tm_query_updated.fetch(keys_only=True)


        if len(tm_result_keys) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            tm_results = ndb.get_multi(tm_result_keys)

            for tm_result in tm_results:
                if len(query) != 0:
                    if query.lower() in tm_result.markName.lower():
                        if len(tm_result.markImgURLS) > 0:
                            markImgURL = tm_result.markImgURLS[0]
                            avail_result = dict(order=tm_result.order,
                                                markName=tm_result.markName,
                                                markImgURLS=markImgURL,
                                                trademarkType=tm_result.trademarkType,
                                                owners=tm_result.ownerNames,
                                                classes=tm_result.classes,
                                                applicationDate=tm_result.applicationDate,
                                                registrationDate=tm_result.registrationDate,
                                                designatedContractedStates=tm_result.designatedContractedStates,
                                                legalStatus=tm_result.legalStatus,
                                                id_=tm_result.key.id(),
                                                applicationNo=tm_result.applicationNo,
                                                registrtionNo=tm_result.registrtionNo,
                                                goodsServices=tm_result.goodsServices[:100] + '...')

                        else:
                            avail_result = dict(order=tm_result.order,
                                                markName=tm_result.markName,
                                                trademarkType=tm_result.trademarkType,
                                                owners=tm_result.ownerNames,
                                                applicationDate=tm_result.applicationDate,
                                                registrationDate=tm_result.registrationDate,
                                                applicationNo=tm_result.applicationNo,
                                                legalStatus=tm_result.legalStatus,
                                                id_=tm_result.key.id(),
                                                classes=tm_result.classes,
                                                designatedContractedStates=tm_result.designatedContractedStates,
                                                officeOfOrigin=tm_result.officeOfOrigin,
                                                flag=tm_result.flag,
                                                client_comment=tm_result.client_comment[:50] + '...',
                                                registrtionNo=tm_result.registrtionNo,
                                                goodsServices=tm_result.goodsServices[:100] + '...')
                        results.append(avail_result)
                else:
                    if len(tm_result.markImgURLS) > 0:
                        markImgURL = tm_result.markImgURLS[0]
                        avail_result = dict(order=tm_result.order,
                                            markName=tm_result.markName,
                                            markImgURLS=markImgURL,
                                            trademarkType=tm_result.trademarkType,
                                            owners=tm_result.ownerNames,
                                            classes=tm_result.classes,
                                            applicationDate=tm_result.applicationDate,
                                            registrationDate=tm_result.registrationDate,
                                            designatedContractedStates=tm_result.designatedContractedStates,
                                            legalStatus=tm_result.legalStatus,
                                            id_=tm_result.key.id(),
                                            applicationNo=tm_result.applicationNo,
                                            registrtionNo=tm_result.registrtionNo,
                                            goodsServices=tm_result.goodsServices[:100] + '...')

                    else:
                        avail_result = dict(order=tm_result.order,
                                            markName=tm_result.markName,
                                            trademarkType=tm_result.trademarkType,
                                            owners=tm_result.ownerNames,
                                            applicationDate=tm_result.applicationDate,
                                            registrationDate=tm_result.registrationDate,
                                            applicationNo=tm_result.applicationNo,
                                            legalStatus=tm_result.legalStatus,
                                            id_=tm_result.key.id(),
                                            classes=tm_result.classes,
                                            designatedContractedStates=tm_result.designatedContractedStates,
                                            officeOfOrigin=tm_result.officeOfOrigin,
                                            flag=tm_result.flag,
                                            client_comment=tm_result.client_comment[:50] + '...',
                                            registrtionNo=tm_result.registrtionNo,
                                            goodsServices=tm_result.goodsServices[:100] + '...')
                    results.append(avail_result)

            avail_tax_item = dict(name=taxonomy_l1.name,
                                    results=results, 
                                    count=len(results),
                                    id_=str(taxonomy_l1.key.id()))

            taxonomy_items.append(avail_tax_item)



    template_args = {'user': user, 
                        'project': project_dict, 
                        'taxonomy_items': taxonomy_items, 
                        'filters': filters_dict, 
                        'results': results}

    self.render_template('filteredtmreport.html', template_args)
```

> just want the search filters to work

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be an equal sing rather that an assignment?

```
 tm_result_keys = tm_query_updated.fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Are you overwriting values here?

```
        if ado == 'between' and len(ad2) != 0:
            tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationDate >= datetime.datetime.strptime(str(ad1), '%m/%d/%Y'))
            tm_query_updated = tm_query_updated.filter(TrademarkResult.applicationDate <= datetime.datetime.strptime(str(ad2), '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Just trying to read through your code to understand it, hopefully, you can do some print outs and see the values here?